# Why does adding image to a google form using Form.addImageItem() result in "Invalid data updating form"?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to automatically insert an image from a Google drive into a Google form with the help of a Google script using the addImage function, which has recently stopped working and leads to the error message 'Invalid data update formular'.

I'm using Google forms to allow users to enter text from images.
Some sort of manual image recognition.
The images are stored on the googel drive in a directory.
A Google script inserts them into a form and adds several questions with short answers, multiple choice questions and page breaks.

So until recently everything worked, but now the addImage function of the form returns the error message

> Invalid data update form.

I have tried to do do the following:

- created a new form with a new script to test addImageItem function (source below)
- tested that all other functions to add items to the form except addImageItem (like addMultipleChoiceItem, addPageBreakItem, addCheckboxItem, addTextItem) still work
- add image manualy to see if that still work
- use other formats as image source (JPG and PNG)
- use different files on the google drive as image source
- use UrlFetchApp.fetch function as image source (like in the [documentation example](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/image-item))

All attempts with addImageItem unsuccessful.
The functions addMultipleChoiceItem, addPageBreakItem, addCheckboxItem, addTextItem return the desired result by adding Items to the form.
Also adding image by hand using the edit form interface stil works.

The images we update are about 60kB in size, about 800x600 px large.

The answers to [this thread from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182861/cannot-add-image-from-google-drive-to-a-google-form-using-apps-script) which looks similar do not help. The error messages in the question are different. I also tried to use the getBlob() and getThumbnail() functions, as mentioned in the answers there, but they also lead to the error 'Invalid data update form'.

```
function myFunction() {
  var form = FormApp.openById("drive_file_id_of_form");
  var img = DriveApp.getFileById("drive_file_id_of_image");
  var imgFormItem = form.addImageItem();
  imgFormItem.setImage(img);
  //var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png');
  //var blob = img.getThumbnail();
  //var blob = img.getBlob();
  //form.addImageItem().setImage(blob);
}
```

According to the [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#addImageItem()), addImage should return a newly created ImageItem as a return value but lead to the error on line 4:

> Invalid data for updating the form. (line4, file "Code")

Can someone please help me find out what is invalid in the form data or in the images I try to add and how to avoid this problem?

Edit: found a fresh [bug tracker id](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135217119) for this topic on google issue tracker